# How to modify the style of a <ReactPlayer /> component

Tags: reactjs, react-player

I would like to modify only the content of reactplayer. That is, the play button, the music track or the background color. I use for that the react-player module. Thanks and have a nice day.

```html
// My app

        <div className="player-wrapper" >
                    <ReactPlayer url="https://soundcloud.com/supperclubmix/black-eye-peas-dirty-bit-remix?utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing"
                        className="react-player"
                        id="music"
                        height="auto"
                        width="90%"
                        controls={true}
                        loop={true}
                    />
                </div>

      </div>
```

```html
//CSS

.player-wrapper {
    
}


.react-player {
    margin-top: 115%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try looking at the docs. If no doc present, then it will be easier to create your own video player component then trying to figure out how to modify the pre-built installed one.